# How to update state in Redux toolkit using websocket in NextJS 14

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, next.js13

Just shows the initial content without updating,how to fix this, Am I also using the wrong socket type? I think issue related with extraReducer, Is it possible that it only works with http requests?, Sorry but I'm new to this socket io, before that i use socket with ordinary useState, and that case it was work perfectly

```js
export const Timer = () => { 
 React.useEffect((): void => {
    dispatch(timerThunk(club._id));
    });
  }, [club._id]);
 }
```

```js
'use client';
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
import { ITimer } from '@/screens/club-control/types';

const createSocket = (clubId: string): Socket => {
  return io('http://localhost:5000', {
    query: {
      club: clubId,
    },
  });
};

export const timerThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'timer/updateTimers',
  async (clubId: string, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const socket = createSocket(clubId);

    return new Promise<ITimer[]>((resolve, reject) => {
      socket.on('timer-updated', (timersData: ITimer[]) => {
        try {
          const parsedData = JSON.parse(String(timersData));
          resolve(parsedData);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(rejectWithValue(error));
        }
      });

      return () => {
        socket.off('timer-updated');
        socket.disconnect();
      };
    });
  }
);
```

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { TTimerInitialState } from '../../types';
import { timerThunk } from '@/redux/http/timerThunk';

const initialState: TTimerInitialState = {
  timers: {
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
    total_items: 0,
    items: [],
  },
};

export const timerSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'timer',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(
        timerThunk.fulfilled,
        (state: TTimerInitialState, action): void => {
          if (action.payload) {
            state.timers = {
              items: action.payload,
              isError: false,
              isLoading: false,
              total_items: 0,
            };
          }
        }
      )

      .addCase(timerThunk.pending, (state: TTimerInitialState): void => {
        state.timers.items = [];
        state.timers.isLoading = true;
        state.timers.isError = false;
      })
      .addCase(timerThunk.rejected, (state): void => {
        state.timers.isLoading = false;
        state.timers.isError = true;
      });
  },
});
export const timerReducer = timerSlice.reducer;
```